# How to create apk file in command line?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, command-line

I was using eclipse ide to build apk file . Now i want to create apk file in command line in linux.
But when i say ant debug it gives following error :

```
Unable to obtain resource from anttasks.jar
  java.util.zip.ZipException : error in opening zip file

Problem : failed to create task or type checkenv 
Cause : The name is undefined 
Action : Check the spelling
Action : Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared
Action : Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place
```

I have ant version 1.9.2 . and android version 17.
I have build.xml file .

Edit : I changed my ant version into 1.8.0 , But whatever i do still i am getting those failed to create task or type checkenv error .

Comment: ant version 1.8.0 is working with me

Comment: Can you check if the anttasks.jar is available and can be reached? If not you can download it.

Comment: How to download anttasks.jar file?

Comment: `anttasks.jar` is part of the Android SDK, it should be at path `$SDK/tools/lib/anttasks.jar`. It seems your file might be corrupted. Does this command work: `jar tf $SDK/tools/lib/anttasks.jar` (where `$SDK` is the path to your Android SDK)

Comment: when gave the command jar tf $SDK/tools/lib/anttasks.jar , it tells java.util.zip.ZipException:error in opening zip file at java.util.zip.ZipException.open (Native Method)

Comment: Try unzipping anttasks.jar. If it is successful ,try compressing the unzipped folder contents again and replace the jar file(take a backup though).

Answer (score 1):

Check this following developer link

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: I know that this is several years old now, but please be aware that link-only answers are [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/191410).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have a file named `local.properties` in the root directory (i.e. same directory as your `build.xml`).

Be sure that this file contains a line like this:

```
sdk.dir=c:\\tools\\android-sdk
```

(Of course you need to adapt the path to your effective sdk location)

Double-check that the path is correct.

Re-run `ant debug`

Note : the file local.properties is local (and is usually not under version control !)

Comment: I have local.properties and sdk.dir path is correct in that . I have checked that already .. That is not the issue

Comment: Can you check that your sdk installation is not corrupted? In particular check that android-sdk/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar exists and is executable.

Comment: I have anttasks.jar file . But can u pls tell me how to check whether its executable or not ??

Comment: `ls -l` in `android-sdk/tools/lib/` : it will give you information about owner/group etc... The owner of the ant process (i.e. you) must have rights to read it (not sure executable is required, but on my install -windows- it is executable)

Comment: @ben75 I have the same issue. I have checked that local.properties,. sdk.dir=E:\\JEGADEES\\Android\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030,. but still same issue is there. Any idea?

but I can't find ant-tasks.jar in E:\JEGADEES\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant the path.

Comment: @ben75 But ant-tasks.jar found in E:\JEGADEES\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\lib path.

Comment: You can try this `ant -lib E:\JEGADEES\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\lib\ant-tasks.jar debug` It will add the jar explicitely to the ant classpath

Comment: now only i noticed your comment. i try and give the feedback soon. at one thing i am not making anything down.

Comment: @ben75 I have tried in Command Prompt,. But It through Build.xml does not exit,. and build failed Error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example
You need to pass `sdk.dir` into ant, i.e. `ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK>`

You'll also need to specify one of the seven or so Android build targets because the default build target is 'help'.

If you just run `ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK>`, you'll get some help output, like so:

```
help:
 [echo] Android Ant Build. Available targets:
 [echo]    help:      Displays this help.
 [echo]    clean:     Removes output files created by other targets.
 [echo]    compile:   Compiles project's .java files into .class files.
 [echo]    debug:     Builds the application and signs it with a debug key.
 [echo]    release:   Builds the application. The generated apk file must be

 [echo]               signed before it is published.
 [echo]    install:   Installs/reinstalls the debug package onto a running
 [echo]               emulator or device.
 [echo]               If the application was previously installed, the
 [echo]               signatures must match.
 [echo]    uninstall: Uninstalls the application from a running emulator or
 [echo]               device.
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds 
To build the APK, you have to specify debug or release.

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to Android SDK> debug
```

This will help you creating an apk file

Comment: if i write ant -Dsdk.dir=<path to android SDK> debug then also i am getting the same error

Comment: @SSS WHY does the build fail?

Comment: That is what i am asking. Why it is giving error as failed to create task or type checkenv and fails??

Answer (score 0):

I am doing like

1) sdk/tools/android update project -t 3 -p

2) ant clean release

3) jarsigner -keystore  -storepass  -keypass

4) sdk/tools/zipalign  -v 4  /bin/.apk

Comment: But for me it says : unable to open zip file anttasks.jar